# NSMutableArray: writing a smaller array into a larger array at a specified location?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

NSMutableArray:   writing a smaller array into a larger array at a specified location?

Is there a method or do I need to use a for-loop?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you read the NSMutableArray documentation, you'd see the [`replaceObjectsInRange:withObjectsFromArray:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectsInRange%3awithObjectsFromArray%3a) method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for either `insertObjects:atIndexes:` or `replaceObjectsInRange:withObjectsFromArray:`. Check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for examples.